# Laravel 5 translate validation attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can i translate the attribute, now the output is:
companyname is verplicht. (dutch)

Validation.php

```
'required'             => ':attribute is verplicht.',
```

Controller:

```
$rules = array(
    'companyname'       => 'required'
;
```

View:

```
{{ Form::text( 'companyname' , null, array( 'class' => 'form-control' ) ) ) }}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to edit the app/resources/lang/your-language/validation.php and at the bottom you will see an **attribute array**.

Following your example just add:

```
'attributes' => [
'companyname' => 'Your Custom Name'
],
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: in the new version of Laravel, this path `app/resources/lang/your-language/validation.php` changed to `app/lang/your-language/validation.php`

Comment: Works like a charm even if you're using the single json file approach. Thank you!